# QT: Checkbox font CHANGES after first click

Tags: qt

I'm having a strange problem in which a font set to a QCheckBox will change font after a first click to either check or uncheck it. I have no idea why.  checkbox is a simple QCheckBox. The font change is subtle. Like from a low resolution font, to anti-aliasing with a slight color change.

I have no code that does that and I have no idea why it's happening.3

the stylesheet:

```
QCheckBox#TestCheck::indicator:checked
{
    image: url(:/images/box_checked.png);
    color: #535353;
}

QCheckBox#TestCheck::indicator:unchecked
{
    image: url(:/images/box_unchecked.png);
    color: #535353;
}
```

my code:

```
    QFont font("Avenir LT Com");
    font.setWeight(QFont::Bold);
    font.setStyleStrategy(QFont::PreferAntialias);
    font.setPixelSize(16);

    this->checkbox = new QCheckBox(this);
    this->shareScreenCheckbox->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("TestCheck"));
    this->checkbox->setGeometry(10, 10, 400, 27);
    this->checkbox->setText("This is a test");
    this->checkbox->setFont(font); 
    this->checkbox->show();
```

The end result:

as you launch...

[image: as you launch...]
first click...

[image: first click]

click again...

[image]

as you can see... font changes do not work. first font is different. click changes the font, and keeps it. What's going on?

Comment: I expanded it to force a font. Still occurs. I'll also elaborate about the CSS.

Comment: Try `QWidget::ensurePolished()`, look it up in the docs.

Comment: ensurePolished has no effect

Comment: Looks like something overrides the bold of the font, to me. Try setting font with style sheet?

Comment: tried that too. still black font first, then tones down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't reproduce your problem, after running your code under qt 5.3. But I had a quite similar problem some time ago, with qt 5.1.1 maybe that workaround helps you too

[QT 5.1.1: Checkbox in QWebview shows strange behavior under Win 7 (x64) / Win 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19941258/qt-5-1-1-checkbox-in-qwebview-shows-strange-behavior-under-win-7-x64-win-8)

```
class CustomStyle : public QProxyStyle
{
    void drawControl(ControlElement element, const QStyleOption* option, QPainter* painter, const QWidget* widget) const
{
    if (element == QStyle::CE_CheckBox && dynamic_cast<QWebView*>(option->styleObject))
        option->styleObject->setProperty("_q_no_animation", true);
    QProxyStyle::drawControl(element, option, painter, widget);
}
};
```

If not, you should write a bugreport at https://bugreports.qt-project.org